# Typo3 9.5.11 wraps <p> around <iframe> (CKEditor?)

Tags: iframe, ckeditor, typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-9.x

I added an iframe to my CKEditor with the embed plugin.

When i try to add in iframe it works and when is save it, it works in frontend and saves it like this in the database:

```
<div data-oembed-url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0DPdy98e4c">
  <div style="left: 0; width: 100%; height: 0; position: relative; padding-bottom: 75%;">
    <iframe allow="encrypted-media; accelerometer; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" scrolling="no" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c?rel=0" style="border: 0; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;" tabindex="-1">
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when i open the editor now again in the backend the iframe is broken, when i click on source it looks like this:

```
<div data-oembed-url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0DPdy98e4c">
  <div style="left: 0; width: 100%; height: 0; position: relative; padding-bottom: 75%;">
     <p>
        &lt;iframe allow="encrypted-media; accelerometer; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" scrolling="no" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c?rel=0" style="border: 0; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;" tabindex="-1"
       &gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
     </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The config for my editor looks like this:

```
editor:

     config:

        removePlugins:
            - null

        removeButtons:
            - Strike

        AllowedContent:
            - true

        allowTagsOutside:
            - iframe

        allowTags:
            - iframe
```

In my Page.ts i added this:

```
RTE {
     default {
        proc.allowTags := addToList(object,param,embed,iframe)
        proc.allowTagsOutside := addToList(object,embed,iframe)
        proc.entryHTMLparser_db.allowTags < .allowTags
        proc.entryHTMLparser_db.allowTags := addToList(iframe) 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think my problem was that my old config in the rte.ts from my typo3 6.x version was still loaded. i added this to my default.yaml:

```
editor:
    processing:
        allowTags:
            - s
            - span
            - iframe
            - i
    HTMLparser_db:
        tags:
        span:
        rmTagIfNoAttrib: false

config:

    allowedContent: true
    removeFormatAttributes: ""

    extraAllowedContent:
        - span
        - iframe
```

and added this to my page.ts

```
RTE.default.proc.blockElementList = PRE,UL,OL,H1,H2,H3,H4,H5,H6,ADDRESS,DL,DD,HEADER,SECTION,FOOTER,NAV,ARTICLE,ASIDE,IFRAME
```

Hope this helps you if you experience the same problem.